# Web2lead success or failure

Tags: web2lead

I've been given a web2lead form to embed on a website, but I don't have experience with Salesforce. I've put the form on the page and tested it and it seems to be working. I see I can designate which page to redirect people after a form submission. However, is there a way after that submission is made for the website to know if the submission successfully made it into Salesforce (some sort of success or failure message from Salesforce)? If, for some reason, the submission doesn't go through, I don't want to send visitors to a page that says "Thanks for contacting us, we'll get back to you." I cannot find any information online for this.

Comment: Related: [Web-to- lead and get back ID in response](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121808).

Answer (score 0):

Web-to-Lead always returns a success message, unless it fails to queue with the server. I've never seen this happen, though I suppose it's theoretically possible. However, the leads are not inserted at that moment. Instead, they're stored in a queue and processed at a later point in time. Since the actual processing occurs later, there's no way to tell if the successful submission will result in the lead being created in Salesforce. For example, a validation rule may block the creation of the record.

Note that administrators will be notified with the details of the lead submission if it fails to insert. If you want to ensure that the lead was actually created, use the SOAP or REST API, which are synchronous, and will provide an immediate result back. Note that if you use this technique, you'll also have to arrange for a local queue of the data on your server in case Salesforce is undergoing maintenance.

If you have a pretty vanilla implementation of Leads (no code or system validation rules), then you can pretty much guarantee the leads will end up in the system sooner or later. If you've got a more complicated setup, you may want to use an actual API to deliver the data safely. Web-to-Lead, while incredibly reliable (>99.999%) when leads are relatively lightweight, there's certainly situations that administrators can create where leads won't be captured, and, despite this, the lead will still be sent to the "thank you" page, since Web-to-Lead has no way to know if an error will happen beforehand.